# (Highcharts) x axis date format doesn't match to tooltip's date format

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgecutioner/hmhpqux9/1/

```
var datagroup = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    datagroup.push([Date.UTC(2014,  i, 27), 5]);
}
$('#container').highcharts({
...
    series: [{
        name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
        data: datagroup
    }]
});
```

You can see the month in x-axis is 1 more month than the month in tooltip.

If I set my data like this sample:
http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7665
the date is matched, however it doesn't if I set my data outside dynamically.

Is this a Highchart bug? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. I think the misunderstanding here is because you are using a `column` chart on a `datetime` axis. The x-axis labels show the start of each month (1. feb). The tooltip shows the date of your column (27. jan).

The labels on the x-axis are placed there to easily show when each month starts. They do not care where you data is placed (unlike on a `linear` or `category` axis where labels are typically directly under your data).

You have added your points on the 27th of each month. Because you use `column` this means that the **center** of each column is that date. But your columns have width! That mean that they go from the a few days before to a few days after the 27th (see how each column ends into the next month). This is different from `line` chart where each point will only represent a single time. The tooltip for your column only shows the date you created that column with (the center value), not the start and end date.

Comment: Thanks for clarify my misunderstanding! It works after I set date's day to 1. day doesn't matter to me and I need to use column chart, thanks again.